# Python: Comparing the speed of NumPy and SymPy ufuncified functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, sympy

Just wrote a code for comparison of speed of calculation for a function which is in written as `numpy` and a function which uses `ufuncify` from `sympy`:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, Matrix
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import ufuncify
u,v,e,a1,a0 = symbols('u v e a1 a0')

dudt = u-u**3-v 
dvdt = e*(u-a1*v-a0)

p = {'a1':0.5,'a0':1.5,'e':0.1}

eqs = Matrix([dudt,dvdt])

numeqs=eqs.subs([(a1,p['a1']),(a0,p['a0']),(e,p['e'])])
print eqs
print numeqs

dudt = ufuncify([u,v],numeqs[0])
dvdt = ufuncify([u,v],numeqs[1])

def syrhs(u,v):
    return dudt(u,v),dvdt(u,v)

def nprhs(u,v,p):
    dudt = u-u**3-v 
    dvdt = p['e']*(u-p['a1']*v-p['a0'])
    return dudt,dvdt

def compare(n=10000):
    import time
    timer_np=0
    timer_sy=0
    error = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        u=np.random.random((128,128))
        v=np.random.random((128,128))
        start_time=time.time()
        npcalc=np.ravel(nprhs(u,v,p))
        mid_time=time.time()
        sycalc=np.ravel(syrhs(u,v))
        end_time=time.time()
        timer_np+=(mid_time-start_time)
        timer_sy+=(end_time-mid_time)
        error[i]=np.max(np.abs(npcalc-sycalc))
    print "Max difference is ",np.max(error), ", and mean difference is ",np.mean(error)
    print "Average speed for numpy ", timer_np/float(n)
    print "Average speed for sympy ", timer_sy/float(n)
```

On my machine the result is:

```
In [21]: compare()
Max difference is  5.55111512313e-17 , and mean difference is  5.55111512313e-17
Average speed for numpy  0.00128133814335
Average speed for sympy  0.00127074036598
```

Any suggestions on how to make either of the above function faster is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further exploration it seems that `ufuncify` and regular `numpy` functions will give more or less the same speed of computation. Using `numba` or printing to `theano` function did not result in a faster code. So the other option to make things faster is either `cython` or wrapping a `c` or `FORTRAN` code.

Comment: Why do you think there's a speed problem?  `nprhs` is straight forward `numpy` without time consuming Python loops.  The dictionary lookups for `p` might slow it a bit, but most of the time spent in the compiled math operations (`-`,`**`, etc).